# Unable to display image using variant with ActiveStorage image_processing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Currently I'm working on a Rails 5.2 application. When I try to display a profile's avatar in a `show.html.erb` template using `variant` it doesn't work

`<%= image_tag @profile.avatar.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]) %>`

I get the following[image]

I'm unable to see the image.

I installed `gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'` in my Gemfile.

Also on `application.rb` I added
 `config.active_storage.variant_processor = :vips`

But still, on the backend I get a 500 error:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/representations/xxxx/steven.jpeg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-26 16:33:21 -0400
Processing by ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_blob_id"=>"xxxxxx", "variation_key"=>"xxxxxx", "filename"=>"steven"}
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/stevenaguilar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Disk Storage (0.1ms) Checked if file exists at key: variants/7rnyyMpZaqXT4RBNtzDqPFqS/477efe2eb62003af0b5b40ec71c56de636f58f942964d830feeed4057b8718a6 (no)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

If I edit to `<%= image_tag @profile.avatar %>` I'm able to see the original image.

here is the `Photo` model:

```
 class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :avatar
 end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of Rails you are using is `5.2`, ActiveStorage of the version has no `variant_processor` option.

`resize_to_fit` is the option belongs to `image_processing`. You install the gem, but the processor is fixed to `mini_magick`. see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb#L117

If you want to keep the version of 5.2, you should follow options provided by `mini_magick`. see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variation.html

If you prefer to use `image_processing` to enjoy convenient options, you should upgrade your Rails version to >= 6.

Comment: I'm on rails 7 and i have image_processing installed and i'm running into the same exact issue.

Comment: this is the only way i can get it to `config.active_storage.variant_processor = :mini_magick` in development.rb and production.rb

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`<%= image_tag @profile.avatar.variant(resize: "100x100") %>`

Comment: An explanation as to how / why this suggestion solves the problem would help this to be a valuable contribution to the site...

Answer (score 0):

The image_processing gem relies on `ImageMagick` to do the actual image transformation. `ImageMagick` isn’t a Ruby gem; it’s distributed as a binary that’s specific to your operating system. You’ll need to install it separately for your operating system:
For Linux use apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then once you have `ImageMagick` installed, you’ll need to restart your Rails app.